# Como hago cargar selects con jQuery, Ajax y Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Como hace, este archivo es cargar la librería de jquery para poder utilizar ajax y el código jquery donde diremos que cuando el select con id country cambie de opción, en el evento change

```
table pp_countries
------------------
id
country_name

table pp_cities
---------------
id
country_ID
city_name
```

El controlador home.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->ads = '';
        $this->ads = $this->ads_model->get_ads();
    }

    public function index()
    {

        //Comuna
        $data['cities_res'] = $this->cities_model->get_all_cities();

        //Cuidad
        $data['country_res'] = $this->countries_model->get_all_countries();

        $this->load->view('home_view',$data);
    }
}
```

el modelo cities_model.php

```
public function get_all_cities($id) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('pp_cities');
        $this->db->order_by("sort_order", "ASC");
        $this->db->order_by("city_name", "ASC");
        $Q = $this->db->get();
        if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
            $return = $Q->result();
        } else {
            $return = 0;
        }
        $Q->free_result();
        return $return;
    }
```

el modelo countries_model.php

```
public function get_all_countries() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('pp_countries');
        $this->db->order_by("id", "ASC");
        $Q = $this->db->get();
        if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
            $return = $Q->result();
        } else {
            $return = 0;
        }
        $Q->free_result();
        return $return;
    }
```

la vista home_search.php

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('buscador/search',array('name' => 'jsearch', 'id' => 'jsearch'));?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
          <!--<input type="text" required name="job_params" id="job_params" class="form-control" placeholder="Job title or Skill" />-->

      <select class="form-control" name="jcountry" id="jcountry">

        <option value="" selected>Select City</option>
        <?php if($country_res): foreach($country_res as $country):?>
          <option value="<?php echo $country->country_name;?>"><?php echo $country->country_name;?></option>
        <?php endforeach; endif;?>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <select class="form-control" name="jcity" id="jcity">

        <option value="" selected>Select City</option>
        <?php if($cities_res): foreach($cities_res as $cities):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $cities->city_name;?>"><?php echo $cities->city_name;?></option>
        <?php endforeach; endif;?>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="submit" name="job_submit" class="btn" id="job_submit" value="Search"  />
    </div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Answer (score 1):

En base a un proyecto que yo tengo de esa misma manera tu código quedaía de la siguiente manera:

**Controlador:**

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->ads = '';
    $this->ads = $this->ads_model->get_ads();
}

public function index()
{
    //Cuidad
    $data['country_res'] = $this->countries_model->get_all_countries();

    $this->load->view('home_view',$data);
}

public function get_cities(){

        $options = "";
        if ($this->input->post('id_country')) {
            $id_country = $this->input->post('id_country');
            $cities_res = $this->cities_model->get_all_cities($id_country);
            foreach ($cities_res as $fila) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $fila->id ?>"><?php echo $city_name ?></option>
                <?php
            }
        }
}
```

}

**Cities_model:**

```
public function get_all_cities($id) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('pp_cities');
        $this->db->where('country_ID', $id);
        $this->db->order_by("sort_order", "ASC");
        $this->db->order_by("city_name", "ASC");
        $Q = $this->db->get();
        if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
            $return = $Q->result();
        } else {
            $return = 0;
        }
        $Q->free_result();
        return $return;
    }
```

**View:**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('buscador/search',array('name' => 'jsearch', 'id' => 'jsearch'));?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
          <!--<input type="text" required name="job_params" id="job_params" class="form-control" placeholder="Job title or Skill" />-->

      <select class="form-control" name="jcountry" id="jcountry">

        <option value="" selected>Select City</option>
        <?php if($country_res): foreach($country_res as $country):?>
          <option value="<?php echo $country->id;?>"><?php echo $country->country_name;?></option>
        <?php endforeach; endif;?>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <select class="form-control" name="jcity" id="jcity">

          <option value=""></option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="submit" name="job_submit" class="btn" id="job_submit" value="Search"  />
    </div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Via Ajax te traes los resultados desde tu controlador.

**Ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#jcountry").change(function () {
                    $("#jcountry option:selected").each(function () {
                        id_country = $('#jcountry').val();
                        $.post("<?php echo base_url() ?>home/get_cities", {
                            id_country: id_country
                        }, function (data) {
                            $("#jcity").html(data);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
```

Para mayor información te podrias apoya del siguiente tutorial:

> https://www.uno-de-piera.com/cargar-select-dependiente-con-ajax-y-codeigniter/